# How can I generate a random matrix on (-1,1) with a specified number of negative values?

Tags: r, matrix

I need to generate multiple 14x14 matrices that contain values between -1 and 1, with 55 randomly arranged negative values in each matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate a vector, first 55 are negative values, remaining are non-negative:

```
c(runif(55,min=-1,max=0),runif(14*14-55,min=0,max=+1))
```

Then we use `sample()` to scramble this vector (thanks to @DanielO for pointing this out!) and wrap this vector into a matrix:

```
nc=14
nr=14

set.seed(111)
M = matrix(sample(
c(runif(55,min=-1,max=0),
runif(nr*nc-55,min=0,max=+1))
),nrow=nr,nc=nc)

table(M<0)
FALSE  TRUE 
  141    55
```